# Solidworks motionstudy/motion study causes parts to "jump"

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, solidworks

([solidworks files here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1G6pZJOcN0G8Zk7YzqGfa1C8KK2aCzxId))

I've made a small assembly thet mooves smoothly manually, but when I try to moove it the same way is motion study, it collides is a strange way... what can be the cause of that?[image: manually]

[image]

Comment: This looks like you have a tangent constraint that is bistable. Add aimit distance mate to stop the runner from being able to fall lower than the minor diameter of the cam.

In future please include a full screenshot so we can see how your mates are set up, or even better include a link to download your problematic model!

Comment: I understand the logic and it did help a lot! but now there are certin points in time when it doesn"t seem to run smoothly, marked in a red mark in the timeline (is there an option to attach a photo or the assembly to a comment?

Comment: I usually recommend https://www.filedropper.com/ as the easiest way to share files - I don't have access to your google drive, you didn't make the link public. To include a photo in a comment, upload directly to e.g. imgur, and paste a link here.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/cam i hope zip is O.K.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General points to note: The "Standard" mates are more robust than the Mechanical mates, and should be used wherever possible. A cam should have one continuous face, you can use the fitspline tool to create this.

See below for how I fixed your model:

[image: fix Cam Screencap]

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks!